# display all k2 items from category and subcategories on 1 page

Tags: joomla, categories, items, k2

Sounds so simple right?

I just need to display all k2 items from a category and all subcategories on 1 page, by default it only displays items from the parent category and after googling this and trying various things, nothing is working, I surely must be missing something this must be very simple.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Hopefully this will help someone, disable 'catelogue mode'